# Using JTS, how to find the nearest point on a polygon's boundary from an outside point?

Tags: topology, jts

Using JTS, how to find the nearest point on a polygon's boundary from an outside point?

Answer (score 11):

Check out the [DistanceOp](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/operation/distance/DistanceOp.html).  It returns an array of Coordinates:

Coordinate[] pts = DistanceOp.closestPoints(poly, outsidePoint);

pts[0] will be the point on the first geometry (in this case the polygon) and pts[1] will be on the second geometry (so, the same outside point you just passed in).

Comment: The solution that says: "Eggplant Jeff" is fantastic. But the newest versions of the [DistanceOP](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.11/jts-1.11-javadoc.jar!/com/vividsolutions/jts/operation/distance/DistanceOp.html) API has been marked the method "closestPoints" as "deprecated". You can use nearestPoints() instead!